# Inequalities involving $E\left(\frac DC\right)$ and $E\left(\frac CD\right)$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expectation

Consider 4 positive random variables, let's call them A,B,C,D and suppose their expectations exist. If the following is true
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[ \frac{D}{C} \Big] > \frac{\mathbb{E}[B]}{\mathbb{E}[A]}
$$

Can I state the following ,
$$
\mathbb{E}\Big[ \frac{C}{D} \Big] < \frac{\mathbb{E}[A]}{\mathbb{E}[B]}
$$

to be true?

Thanks a lot to anyone who can shed light on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be refrased as:

> If the expectations exist, then do we always have $\mathsf EX\mathsf EX^{-1}<1$ for positive random variable $X$?

The answer is: "no".

E.g. let $X$ have distribution $\mathsf P(X=2)=\frac12=\mathsf P(X=\frac1{2})$ so that $X$ and $X^{-1}$ have equal distribution with $\mathsf EX=\frac54=\mathsf EX^{-1}.$

It fits in your question by taking $C=1=A=B$ and $D=X$.

Comment: +1. As often, the first reduction step matters. This can be completed by the fact that the only case where $EXEX^{-1}\leqslant1$ is when $X$ is almost surely constant.